# Image not displaying in html image tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

I am getting this response from the server for a jpeg image get request(with CORS):
ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛ  ( %!1"%)+.............

After converting this to base64 it using btoa(encodeURIComponent(data)) looks like:
data:image/jpeg;base64,JUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJTAwJTEwSkZJRiUwMCUwMSUwMSUwMSUwMEglMDBIJTAwJTAwJUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJTAwJUVGJUJGJUJERXhpZiUwMCUwME1NJTAwKiUwMCUwMCUwMCUwOCUwMCUw...............................

On setting the img tag src attribute to the base64 above the image is not rendering in the browser.

However, when I open the image link in the browser tab, it loads properly. Also, on sending the same request in postman it renders the image in the response, in postman.

Even using the blob approach doesn't work (used bower: angular-img-http-src)

```
$scope.$watch('objectURL', function (objectURL) {
    elem.attr('src', objectURL);
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    revokeObjectURL();
});

$http.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
            var blob = new Blob(
                        [ response.data ], 
                        { type: response.headers('Content-Type') }
                    );

            $scope.objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

});
```

Kindly help here.

Answer (score 0):

### In Service:

```
yourService : function(options) {

return $http.get(url, {
                    responseType : 'arraybuffer'
                }

        ).success(function(data) {
            var file = new Blob([ data ], {
                type : 'image/jpeg'
            });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            if(options && options.successCallBack) {
                return options.successCallBack(fileURL, {});
            }
        });
    },
```

### In Controller:

```
function yourImageSuccessHandler(fileUrl, options) {
            $scope.objectUrl= fileUrl; // now you will have fileUrl in 
                                      // controller
        }
        yourService.getDownloadDoc(empId, {
            successCallBack: yourImageSuccessHandler
        });
```

### In template HTML:

```
<img ng-src={{objectUrl}}></img>
```

Comment: The objecturl gets generated Eg: src="blob:http://localhost:8888/138b4e68-e4fe-4495-8fef-016ed34e3e99", but this doesn't get rendered

Comment: try src="localhost:8888/138b4e68-e4fe-4495-8fef-016ed34e3e9‌​9" manually if it works than blob: is additional thing here.

Comment: If I update the existing image src it doesn't work. But on creating a new image like above and then adding to html, this works. Also, needed to add responseType : 'arraybuffer'. Thanks

Comment: @RohitS so your issue is fixed now?

Comment: Yes it is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know if there's a specific angular routine, the general JS solution for created images goes something like this...

```
function addIMG(durl, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        callback(this);
    }, false);
    img.src = durl;
}

addIMG(objectURL, function(img) {
    $('#element').appendChild(img);
});
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: If I update the existing image src it doesn't work. But on creating a new image like above and then adding to html, this works.